# iFrame don't want to display

Tags: html, magento, iframe, drupal

I have 2 site:
  - drupal website
  - magento website

In my drupal website I want to display an iFrame of my magento website but this makes me an error:

```
Refused to display 'https://magento_site.com?_redirect_url=https://drupal_site.com' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://drupal_site.com https://magento_site.com".
```

I've seen that this kind of error is a problem of the displayed website which don't allow to the other website to display it.

How can I allow this ? How I need to modify to make it works ?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your drupal version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because of Content-Security-Policy, So you can handle it by installing [Content-Security-Policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/csp) module

> Configure a Content-Security-Policy header for your Drupal site.
>   Features
>   Integrates with Drupal's Libraries API to automatically generate a policy for your site
>   Up-to-date with the latest CSP Level 3 Working Draft
>   Policy is automatically optimized to remove duplicate directives and reduce header length
>   Integration with Reporting module for local policy violation logging
>   Integration with Report-URI.com for remote policy violation logging